# Disable intellij indexing with regex

Tags: intellij-idea, indexing, intellij-13

This question is related to [Disable intellij indexing on specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535288/disable-intellij-indexing-on-specific-folder) .

However, we have regression tests that run in directories that will be created and timestamped on the fly.  Is there a way to disable indexing based on a regex?  Or maybe on all subfolders?

Comment: Do the regression test create files in a single directory or is it created in multiple directories ?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. You could try to parse your iml-file and add `<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/your_folder" />` manually.

Comment: @vatsal A test consists of a directory with 3 xml files.  When a test is run it creates a new directory inside of itself with a timestamp.

Comment: I wonder if this may be possible under File -> Project Structure -> Sources (tab) -> Exclude files (field), but I was not able to find any documentation for the field.