# webstorm/intellij: display excluded folders without indexing it

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In webstorm, is there a way to exclude a folder ([hence avoid indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535288/disable-intellij-indexing-on-specific-folder)), but at the same time make it visible in the project structure tree? If I do exclude, it would become invisible. I read about `custom scope`, but it looks like it is for code inspection,... Also, the folder in question is not a library, but some generated one.

For an example use case, I wanted to see my `.tmp` folder always, but not to index it as the content may keep changing. THis triggers reindexing and bit resource hungry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA 14 and WebStorm 9 which just have been released display excluded folders in Project View, but don't index them.