# Disable intellij indexing folder but keep folder in build/vcs

Tags: javascript, extjs, intellij-idea

I am having problems with Intellij indexing taking a long time.
The reason seems to be that I am using Sencha ExtJS javascript library and because the project has to contain all of the source(about 10000 files) these are getting added to the index. With some four different projects each with a copy - you can imagine the problem. As files are globally indexed by Intellij and not per project, this is causing problems.

It seems to state that you can exclude a folder by using mark directory as excluded. However this excludes the files from deployment and VCS - not something I want to do. As during development these are linked directly, if they are not deployed, the code does not work. Also as there are different versions of the libraries I am keen to keep them in source control so that the project when checked out contains the correct version.

Others have found the same issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535288/disable-intellij-indexing-on-specific-folder) so I am wondering if anyone has found a better solution

Comment: Try symbolic links. Seems to work for me (although the libs I'm using are rather small .. but I do see the difference in indexing such folders (_much_ faster))

Comment: @LazyOne I am not on linux. Also I want to keep these files in Source Control so that would cause an issue there. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: 1) Sure. Just keep in mind -- it's 2016 already -- Windows supports symlinks since Vista (or Win7 at least). 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537 -- accordingly to that ticket folders marked as excluded still can participate in upload/vcs

Comment: ok I will try with Links.The main problem I had was that I am running in Tomcat and the deploy does not deploy excluded folders!

Comment: aha noticed there is also a synchonise option that causes writes the file to the excluded directories to the application server so it is less of an issue.Thanks anyway for your suggestions