# How to set indexing locations in AppCode?

Tags: indexing, appcode

AppCode is indexing my entire home folder including places like `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/...` and `~/Dropbox/` etc. which is taking eons. I know I can invalidate my cache and restart, but then it will try to index everything again.

Is there a way to limit the locations where AppCode indexes? or to see what paths it tries to index?

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535511) doesn't work as I don't have my entire home folder in the project (that I know of).
This answer seems to only work for Java projects (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598530).
This answer just causes an endless loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283641

Comment: Your project's search paths might accidentally contain a reference to your home directory, or it might just be a bug. If you [create an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) we can take a look for you.

Comment: Is there any way to see how the index directories are found? For instance, this -> that -> that

Comment: Would appreciate marking my answer as the correct answer if you think it is.

Answer (score 5):

In AppCode, navigate to the files navigator.

[image: Files navigator]

Then you can right click on any folder and exclude it.

[image: Exclude folder]

Comment: Saved my day! For me, it wasn't setting everything as "Excluded", but rather setting the correct folder as the "Project Sources and Headers".