# Low PhpStorm performance with npm run watch

Tags: webpack, indexing, phpstorm, laravel-mix

I use Laravel Mix to compile CSS and JS codes. I use PhpStorm as my editor.

When I run `npm run watch` to automatically build my codes when I edit CSS and JS files, PhpStorm will start indexing compiled codes and if I make a small change in my files PhpStorm will indexing all the built codes again.

PhpStorm's performance is then very bad when using `npm run watch` command.

How to fix this?

Comment: Where is your compiled code located? In a folder?

Comment: If so you might find your answer here: [Disable intellij indexing on specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535288/disable-intellij-indexing-on-specific-folder)

Comment: @PaulStenne when I using npm run watch command in laravel mix , and that is located in /public/css, /public/js directories

Comment: So as the linked question shows, you should just exclude the `/public` folder from PhpStorm =) (Or just the `css` and `js` subfolders in case you would still want to index pictures or stuff)