# How to stop indexing the Maven "target" auto-generated folder?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is there a for Intellij to stop indexing auto-generated folder e.g. Maven target folder. It is very slow and hinders productivity when it starts indexing after building and running a project.

Specifically when I run `mvn jetty:run` it starts indexing when the target gets created with the compiled files. The indexing is painfully slow and happens every run which is causing developer time (a lot).

*For a project with a huge code base, this indexing time is very slow.*

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this folder? Note that if this folder contains source code - IDE needs it for the compilation and code navigation in project.

Answer (score 1):

You can Mark target folder as Excluded in the File | Project Structure | Modules | Sources tab.

Edit: also make sure it's not added as a library in the project.

[image]

See here [Disable intellij indexing on specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535288/disable-intellij-indexing-on-specific-folder)